# Fast excel exporting the file however it is not downloading - php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I am using fast-excel https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/fast-excel to export data from laravel. My Code looks like:

```
public function export(Request $request,$property_id)
    {
        $reviews = Review::with(['unit','amenityValue','amenityValue.amenity','amenityValue.amenity.category','amenityValue.unitAmenityValues'])
            ->where('property_id',$property_id)
            ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
            ->get();
        $file_name = 'review-' . time() . '.xlsx';
        $file_path = storage_path('app/public/exports/'.$file_name);

        (new FastExcel($reviews))->export($file_path , function ($review) {
            if ($review->status != 3) {
                if ($review->action == 2) {
                    $count_num = (int)count($review->amenityValue->unitAmenityValues);
                    $unit_num = 'Multiple';
                } elseif ($review->action == 5) {
                    $count_num = (int)0;
                    $unit_num = '';
                } else {
                    $count_num = (int)1;
                    $unit_num = $review->unit->unit_number;
                }

                if ($review->status == 1) {
                    $action = 'Pending';
                } else {
                    $action = 'Accepted';
                }

                return [
                    'Total Units' => $count_num,
                    'Unit Number' => $unit_num,
                    'Category Name' => ($review->amenityValue) ? $review->amenityValue->amenity->category->category_name : '',
                    'Amenity Name' => ($review->amenityValue) ? $review->amenityValue->amenity->amenity_name : '',
                    'New Amenity Value' => $review->new_amenity_value,
                    'Old Amenity Value' => $review->old_amenity_value,
                    'Action' => $action
                ];

            }
        });
```

This works totally fine ande create an exported file on the destination folder ,however, if I changed this `export` to `download` as

```
(new FastExcel($reviews))->download($file_name, function ($review) { //updated filename as well
```

than this does not work. By the way it does not throws any errors nor force file to download.

**Update**: It looks like I was missing to return however, adding `return` returns data with some weird characters as the xhr response instead of downloading the file. Now, my code looks as shown in attached image.

```
return (new FastExcel($reviews))->download($file_name, function ($review) {
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: are you `return`ing that statement?

Comment: @lagbox Did you mean returning those data? With `return` I am trying to write data on `xlsx` with key being header and right value is the value for that column.

Comment: i assume the download method is something that returns the excel file for downloading? i mean literally using the `return` statement to return what ever is returned from the call to `download`

Comment: @lagbox i don't think I understand exactly what you are saying. However, could you show me an example how can I download the excel file using fast excel?

Comment: @lagbox I think you were mentioning about return could you check now. I have updated the question

Comment: Try adding    
`header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");`
`header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xlsx");`
before you do the download

Comment: @PavelLint where should I add it?

Comment: anywhere before the return statement. You could add it right after the function starts.

Comment: @PavelLint nothing changed

Comment: @PavelLint you choud check the iamge i have attached in the question

Answer (score 0):

Change The request method to Get then download was working

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed mine. If you want to download the excel file you should use the method `->download('filename.xlsx')` instead of `->export('filename.xlsx')`.

- `export` - saves the file by default in public
- `download` - does it

```php
// controller
public function export() 
{
   return fastexcel(collect([['Test']]))->download('filename.xlsx');
}
```

See their readme - https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/fast-excel#export

in frontend, can use `window.open('/endpoint/download', '_blank')`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Repository https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/fast-excel


When you are doing:

```
dd( new FastExcel(collect(["Test"])))->export(storage_path('app/public/file.xlsx')));

// You are getting the route where this file was storad, some like this :  
'storage/app/public/file.xlsx';

// For you can download this file, use:  
Storage::download(Storage::files("public/")[0]);
```